# How to customize dropdown in AngulrJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have faced some problem in AngularJS dropdown text. Please check below my code

**JS**

```
$scope.work_type_list = {
    model: null,
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Print Ready File', symbol: 'P'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Design Work', symbol: 'D'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Design Only', symbol: 'DO'}
    ]
};
```

**My HTML**

```
<select class="form-control m-b" name="work_type" ng-model="formData.work_type" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in work_type_list.availableOptions">
   <option value="">Select Work Type</option>
</select>
```

My current output is -

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in work_type_list.availableOptions" ng-model="formData.work_type" name="work_type" class="form-control m-b ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
  <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Select Work Type</option>
  <option label="Print Ready File" value="string:1">Print Ready File</option>
  <option label="Design Work" value="string:2">Design Work</option>
  <option label="Design Only" value="string:3">Design Only</option>
</select>
```

I want to add `P`, `D` and `DO` of my options text. Here my output should be like this -

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in work_type_list.availableOptions" ng-model="formData.work_type" name="work_type" class="form-control m-b ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
  <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Select Work Type</option>
  <option label="Print Ready File" value="string:1">Print Ready File(P)</option>
  <option label="Design Work" value="string:2">Design Work(D)</option>
  <option label="Design Only" value="string:3">Design Only(DO)</option>
</select>
```

How to customize dropdown option text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expressions in the various parts of `ng-options`:

```
<select class="form-control m-b" name="work_type" ng-model="formData.work_type"
    ng-options="option.id as (option.name + '(' + option.symbol + ')') for option in work_type_list.availableOptions">
    <option value="">Select Work Type</option>
</select>
```